# Any reason to base call event handlers in Page in a derived page - WP 8.1

Tags: inheritance, windows-phone-8.1, eventhandler

In WP 8.1, the `Page` class has the following event handlers:

```
protected virtual void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e);

protected virtual void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e);

protected virtual void OnNavigatingFrom(NavigatingCancelEventArgs e);
```

Is there any reason for a sub page to call these base handlers while overriding them? I can't tell if `Page` does anything useful with these. Should I ignore or invoke them?

Answer (score 1):

Right now they don't do anything, but what if it changed in a future version? Out of principle, it's best to call the base event handler. If the base method is empty, the call will likely be optimized by the JIT compiler anyway.

Comment: Should the base method be called before or after the sub class code runs inside of each event handler?

Comment: @Mark13426 Doesn't change much in this case since the event handlers are empty, but I usually try to order them logically. With `OnNavigatedTo` for instance, you usually want to execute code *after* the navigation, so I first call the base method then my code. On the other hand, with `OnNavigatedFrom`, you usually want to execute your code before leaving the page, so I put it before the base event.